# Python read file N line convert into 1 line

Tags: python

Read N line file and display in one line.

i tried used list but cant make it.

```
a=open("txt","r")
b=a.read()
c=b.split()
```

The file got line 1 a,line 2 b,line 3 c,i need read the file and display abc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `readlines()`:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

print("".join(c.strip() for c in content))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `readlines()` to read all lines and `join` them:

```
with open('some.txt', 'r') as f:
    print(''.join(list(map(str.strip, f.readlines()))))
```

Comment: You could replace `lambda x: x.strip()` with simply just `str.strip` (no parentheses, just the function)

Comment: @NChauhan, oops that's fine. Thanks.